# Disable WAL mode

Tags: android, sqlite

It seems like my solution is not working and I don't know why. Here is what I try:

**Logic**

My app has a single database instance and if this instance is created does following:

1. Get current database mode
2. If current database mode == wal mode, I change it to persist
3. change mode to persist
4. Check if new mode is persist
5. creates the single database instance and reuses it as long as the app's process lives

**Code**

```
// this object holds the ONLY instance of my database and initialises it lazily!
object DBManagerImpl : IDBManager {

    val TAG = "DB-MANAGER"

    internal val database: Database by lazy {

        // 1) change db mode if necessary
        DBJournalUtil.logInfos(null)
        val mode = DBJournalUtil.getDBMode(null)
        L.tag(DBJournalUtil.TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "DB journal_mode: $mode" }
        if (mode.equals(DBJournalUtil.JOURNAL_MODE_WAL, true))
        {
            DBJournalUtil.disableWALMode()
            val mode2 = DBJournalUtil.getDBMode(null)
            L.tag(DBJournalUtil.TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "DB journal_mode - AFTER DISABLE: $mode2" }
        }

        // 2) create single database instance
        L.tag(TAG).d { "database variable created!" }
        val database = Database()

        database
    }
}
```

In general, this is the main code part:

```
    // 1) disable the wal journal mode and change it to persist
    DBJournalUtil.disableWALMode()
    // 2) check the new journal mode => Problem: it's still WAL and not persist
    val mode2 = DBJournalUtil.getDBMode(null)
```

**Problem**

It looks like that my code does correctly change the database mode (based on log line 8) but then in log line 10 it again reports back wal mode. Why? What am I missing or doing wrong here?

**Produced log output**

> 1 [[ DBJournalUtil:14 b]]: LOG 2 - journal_mode: wal
>
> 2 [[ DBManagerImpl$database:6 e]]: DB journal_mode: wal
>
> 3 [[ DBJournalUtil:23 a]]: Change DB journal_mode from WAL to PERSIST - current journal_mode = wal
>
> 4 [[ DBJournalUtil:35 b]]: wal_checkpoint - BEFORE wal(TRUNCATE): Busy = 0, LOG = 0, CHECKPOINTED = 0
>
> 5 [[ DBJournalUtil:6 c]]: Checkpoint (TRUNCATE): count = 1
>
> 6 [[ DBJournalUtil:35 b]]: wal_checkpoint - AFTER wal(TRUNCATE): Busy = 0, LOG = 0, CHECKPOINTED = 0
>
> 7 [[ DBJournalUtil:48 a]]: setJournalMode: count = 1
>
> 8 [[ DBJournalUtil:32 a]]: New journal_mode: persist **// <= HERE it is persist!**
>
> 9 [[ DBJournalUtil:42 a]]: Changed DB journal_mode from WAL to PERSIST!
>
> 10 [[ DBManagerImpl$database:12 e]]: DB journal_mode - AFTER DISABLE: wal **// <= WHY is it still wal mode and not persist??????**
>
> 11 [[ DBManagerImpl$database:15 e]]: database variable created!

**Code - DBJournalUtil**

```
object DBJournalUtil {

    val TAG_WAL_MODE = "DB-WAL-MODE"

    val JOURNAL_MODE_WAL = "WAL"
    val JOURNAL_MODE_PERSIST = "PERSIST"

    val JOURNAL_MODE_DELETE = "DELETE"
    val JOURNAL_MODE_TRUNCATE = "TRUNCATE"

    fun logInfos(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

        var csr: Cursor? = null
        var dbToUse: SQLiteDatabase? = null

        val dbName = DBManagerProvider.get().dbFileName()
        val dbFile = AppProvider.get().context.getDatabasePath(dbName)

        val logFile = { file: File ->
            val path = file.absolutePath
            val exists = file.exists()
            val size = file.length()
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "LOG 1 - file: $path | exists: $exists | size: $size" }
        }

        // 1) Dateien loggen
        logFile(dbFile)
        logFile(File(dbFile.getPath() + "-wal")) // WAL Mode file
        logFile(File(dbFile.getPath() + "-shm")) // WAL Mode file

        try {
            dbToUse = db
                    ?: SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)

            // 2) journal-mode loggen
            csr = dbToUse!!.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode", null)
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                val mode = csr.getString(0)
                L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "LOG 2 - journal_mode: $mode" }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).e(e)
        } finally {
            csr?.close()
            if (db == null)
                dbToUse?.close()
        }
    }

    fun getDBMode(db: SQLiteDatabase?): String? {

        var mode: String? = null
        var csr: Cursor? = null
        var dbToUse: SQLiteDatabase? = null

        val dbName = DBManagerProvider.get().dbFileName()
        val dbFile = AppProvider.get().context.getDatabasePath(dbName)

        try {
            dbToUse = db
                    ?: SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)

            csr = dbToUse!!.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode", null)
            if (csr.moveToFirst())
                mode = csr.getString(0)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).e(e)
        } finally {
            csr?.close()
            if (db == null)
                dbToUse?.close()
        }

        return mode
    }

    fun disableWALMode() {

        val modeFrom = JOURNAL_MODE_WAL
        val modeTo = JOURNAL_MODE_PERSIST

        val dbName = DBManagerProvider.get().dbFileName()
        val dbFile = AppProvider.get().context.getDatabasePath(dbName)

        var db: SQLiteDatabase? = null

        try {

            // 1) Datenbank öffnen
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)

            // 2) Modus auslesen
            val mode = getDBMode(db)
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "Change DB journal_mode from $modeFrom to $modeTo - current journal_mode = $mode" }

            if (mode == null || mode.equals(modeTo, true)) {
                L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "Abbruch da aktueller journal_mode = $mode" }
            } else {

                // 3) wal_checkpoint ausführen
                walCheckpoint(db, "BEFORE wal(TRUNCATE)")

                // 4) wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE) ausführen um pending operations in DB zu übertragen
                walTruncate(db)

                // 5) wal_checkpoint ausführen
                walCheckpoint(db, "AFTER wal(TRUNCATE)")

                // 6) journal_mode ändern
                setJournalMode(db, modeTo)

                // 7) nochmals aktuellen journal_mode holen
                val newMode = getDBMode(db)
                L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "New journal_mode: $newMode" }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).e(e)
        } finally {
            db?.close()
        }

        L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "Changed DB journal_mode from $modeFrom to $modeTo!" }
    }

    private fun walCheckpoint(db: SQLiteDatabase, logTag: String) {
        var wal_busy = -99
        var wal_log = -99
        var wal_checkpointed = -99

        var csr: Cursor? = null

        try {
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint", null)
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                wal_busy = csr.getInt(0)
                wal_log = csr.getInt(1)
                wal_checkpointed = csr.getInt(2)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).e(e)
        } finally {
            csr?.close()
        }

        L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "wal_checkpoint - $logTag: Busy = $wal_busy, LOG = $wal_log, CHECKPOINTED = $wal_checkpointed" }
    }

    private fun walTruncate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        var csr: Cursor? = null
        try {
            // Checkpoint - Pending Operationen in DB überführen
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)", null)
            val count = csr.count
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "Checkpoint (TRUNCATE): count = $count" }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).e(e)
        } finally {
            csr?.close()
        }
    }

    private fun setJournalMode(db: SQLiteDatabase, mode: String) {
        var csr: Cursor? = null
        try {
            // Checkpoint - Pending Operationen in DB überführen
            csr = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=$mode", null)
            val count = csr.count
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).d { "setJournalMode: count = $count" }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            L.tag(TAG_WAL_MODE).e(e)
        } finally {
            csr?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to change WAL mode in first place? Sqlite should work fine with default db/wal settings

Comment: I don't "need" it, I just want it. My database is always loaded in a rx based memory structure so no need to enable any database optimisations. Simply truncate mode would be preferred by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at Section 3.3 of https://sqlite.org/wal.html you can only persist turning WAL mode on, you cannot persist turning WAL mode off. You can only turn WAL mode off as part of each connection and that setting will be forgotten when you close the database.